# Term for particularizing someone's behavior in a discussion where they aim at avoiding to be blamed for having a double standard

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term in English which describes the act of adding details to some case to differentiate it from another so as to avoid getting to the same conclusion?

For example let's take the following (non-sense) dialog:

- I am tired of your impoliteness, you always open the door without knocking first
- Didn't you do the same yesterday?
- No, yesterday was the kitchens door, in that case it is not impolite.
- But you also blamed me when I opened the kitchens door last time.
- Last time it was in the afternoon, you know in the afternoon I am working in the kitchen.
- I also work sometimes in the kitchen, you don't seem to remember to knock then.
- Yes but you work with the computer and when I am working I am usually on the phone.

... etc

By particularizing ad infinitum one would virtually always be right, since rarely two situations can be identical. How is this called? Or how would a person who does this be called?

Comment: Double standard?  https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/227/Double-Standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **explain away** a phrasal verb:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/explain+away)

> to dismiss or minimize the significance of (something) by means of an
>   explanation or excuse

As in:

There is no way to explain away my carelessness.

Comment: I think this one fits quite good the term I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the senses of rationalise / rationalising covers this, though it is broader in scope:

> **rationalise** ['BrE' spelling] verb ...
>
> 1 Attempt to explain or justify (behaviour or an attitude) with
>   logical reasons, even if these are not appropriate.

{[**ODO**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rationalize)} (ODO does not mention the intransitive usage; [**M-W**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rationalize) does.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that such persons as you try to characterise could be dubbed as being given to [tergiversation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tergiversation).

> evasion of straightforward action or clear-cut statement

I'm not aware of a one-word term that could be put for this phrase, though.

Comment: Nice word even if it's not a 100% fit. I edited to add definition and link.